# data disappear out of UNIUrlConnection

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, unirest

What I'm trying to do is to pass data from my Objective-C to my swift file.

Recently, when I have successfully connected my objective c file with my swift file, I can print data that get from UNIUrlConnection(which means the connection between swift and objective-c works fine).

Then I create a NSMutableDictionary object and add those data into NSMutableDictionary. I want to pass this NSMutableDictionary object to my swift file so that I can output them on my viewController.

However, the NSMutableDictionary contains correct data within the UNIUrlConnection but then contains none out of UNIUrlConnection. Thus the NSMutableDictionary passed to swift file would always contain no data. How can I solve this?

This is my objective c file.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UNIRest.h>
#import "findByIngredients.h"

@implementation findByIngredients

-(NSMutableDictionary*) connectAPI:(NSString*) ingredients Number:(NSString*) number{

NSMutableDictionary *temp = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:10];

NSString* url = @"https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.mashape.com/recipes/findByIngredients?fillIngredients=false";
if (![ingredients  isEqual: @""]) {
    NSString* ingre = @"&ingredients=";
    ingre = [ingre stringByAppendingString:ingredients];
    url = [url stringByAppendingString:ingre];
}
else {
    NSString* ingre = @"&ingredients=<required>";
    url = [url stringByAppendingString:ingre];
}
NSString* LL = @"&limitLicense=false";
url = [url stringByAppendingString:LL];
if (![number  isEqual: @""]) {
    NSString* numberOfReturn = @"&number=";
    numberOfReturn = [numberOfReturn stringByAppendingString:number];
    url = [url stringByAppendingString:numberOfReturn];
}
NSString* ranking = @"&ranking=1";
url = [url stringByAppendingString:ranking];

// These code snippets use an open-source library. http://unirest.io/objective-c
NSDictionary *headers = @{@"X-Mashape-Key": @"KEY", @"Accept": @"application/json"};
UNIUrlConnection *asyncConnection = [[UNIRest get:^(UNISimpleRequest *request) {
    [request setUrl:url];
    [request setHeaders:headers];
}] asJsonAsync:^(UNIHTTPJsonResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSInteger code = response.code;
    NSDictionary *responseHeaders = response.headers;
    UNIJsonNode *body = response.body;
    NSData *rawBody = response.rawBody;

    if (rawBody) {
        id allKeys = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:rawBody options:0 error:&error];

        for (int i=0; i<[allKeys count]; i++) {
            NSDictionary *arrayResult = [allKeys objectAtIndex:i];
            // NSString* myNewString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
            NSString *key = [arrayResult objectForKey:@"id"];
            NSString *value = [arrayResult objectForKey:@"title"];
            [temp setObject:value forKey:key];
            NSLog(@"id=%@",[arrayResult objectForKey:@"id"]);
            NSLog(@"title=%@",[arrayResult objectForKey:@"title"]);
        }
    }

    int size = [temp count];
    NSLog(@"temp size is %d",size);

    NSLog(@"successfully test API");
}];

// int size = [temp count];
// NSLog(@"temp size is %d",size);

return temp;
}

@end
```

Here the size of temp within UNIUrlConnection is correct. But if I put the size before return (which I comment out), it shows 0, which is wrong.

This is my swift file.

```
@IBAction func search(_ sender: Any) {

    let ingreArr = IngredientsText.text.components(separatedBy: [",", " "])
    var ingre:String = ingreArr[0]
    let sep:String = "%2C"
    for (index,element) in ingreArr.enumerated() {
        if (index >= 1) {
            ingre = ingre + sep + element
        }
    }
    let test = findByIngredients()
    // test.connectAPI(ingre, number: NumberOfResults.text)
    let result: Dictionary = test.connectAPI(ingre, number: NumberOfResults.text) as Dictionary

    let num:Int = result.count

    print(num)
}
```

The num is 0.

Comment: `asyncConnection` & `asJsonAsync:` This gives mis a lot of impression that that is async. My guess? `print(num)` is called BEFORE `NSLog(@"dic3 size is %d",size);`. Use a closure/block.

Comment: You are right, print(num) is called before NSLog. What I'm trying to do is to pass the NSMutableDictionary from my Objective-C to my swift file. However, it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: You have to create a block (in Objective-C) and use it in Swift (that's called a Closure). There are plenty of question about that, but in only one language, but the logic is the same.

Comment: Sorry... After searching for block and closure, I still have no idea on how to change my code... I'm quite new to objective c and swift. Could you please give more info like an example so that I can try? Many thanks...

Comment: `-(void) connectAPI:(NSString*) ingredients number:(NSString*)number withBlock:(void (^)(NSMutableDictionary *))block;`...`int size = [temp count]; if (block){block(temp);}` For the Swift part, I don't use Swift, so I won't know.